# Linking Outpan's PHP API with Android

Tags: api, barcodes

I have successfully integrated Zxing's Bar-code Scanning Library with my android app. So, now I am able to get bar-code data of any product.

Now, the problem that has arised is I need to link Outpan's PHP API with my android app. I tried a lot, but failed each and every time. Please help me guys. Please do write the entire code if possible, for integration the PHP API with my app.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358203/android-barcode-scanner-with-outpan-database) also ain't helping me.

This is the [link](https://www.outpan.com/developers.php) for Outpan's PHP API. And yes, I shall keep my PHP file on a web server.

Please do not down-vote my question, as I have done a lot of research and tried a lot before asking this question! Please do understand!

Please do help me!

Comment: most please help me with code questions belong on stackoverflow. and even then, you're going to have to post what you've done in code for anyone to help you out. post your code, its a good start

Comment: @albert: Actually that's the problem.I tried many times. Now i don't know how that code (file) got deleted. Some problem occured on my laptop unfortunately. So, i no longer have the code. That's the problem. :(